# Generate locations of K drones uniformly distributed over a hollow sphere in matlab using inverse transform sampling

Tags: matlab, geometry, scatter-plot, cdf, inverse-transform

The spherical coordinates are (r, theta, phi). And the distribution is given below.

[image]

[image]

To generate the position, I'm using inverse transform sampling, and for plotting I'm transforming them in (X, Y, Z) coordinate.
I was expecting to see dots spreaded over a hollow sphere, but something bizarre is coming. And I couldn't figure out what is the problem.
Here is the Matlab code

```
K=200; 
u=rand([1 K]);
phi_array=2*pi.*u;          
theta_array=acos(1-2.*u);

R_M=160;
R_m=10;
r_k= (R_m^3+(R_M^3-R_m^3).*u).^(1/3);
X=r_k .* cos(phi_array) .* sin(theta_array);
Y=r_k .* sin(phi_array) .* sin(theta_array);
Z=r_k .* cos(theta_array);
scatter3(X,Y,Z);
```

And here is the plot of this file 
[image]

Can you help me to point out what is wrong in my code?
Theoretically, I know there is not any problem but don't know what's causing the error.
I know there are other ways to generate these locations, but I'm interested to know what's the problem in my code.

Comment: I think the problem is that you have only a single dependent, albeit random variable. You use the same `u` to determine `R, theta, phi` with the same formula. In other words: you have a 1D line with points randomly distributed over them, which is exactly what you see in your image. Use `u=rand(k,3)` and then column 1 for `R`, column 2 for `theta` and column 3 for `phi` to get independent random variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That actually worked . But can you explain to me more how is that working? I mean I thought using a single random variable for each R , theta, phi but what you are saying is that by doing so I'm making them dependent of each other right? And I guess That's why I need to use 3 random variables .

Comment: Yea, basically what you have is `r=r(x), theta = theta(x), phi = phi(x)`, i.e. all three variables are dependent on a single, same other variable: `x`. The relationship between `r, theta, phi` is fixed, you coded them the be. This means that you define a line (3D in spherical coordinates) and the *only* thing that differs along that line is where you decide to place your points. Thus, as you see in your image, you have a line with points randomly distributed along that. By making three different random variables there no longer is a constant relationship that holds for all points.